# How to analyze a String in Java in order to tell if it is a word or total gibberish?

Tags: java, string, spam, spam-prevention, lexical-analysis

I need to analyze a String in Java in order to tell if it contains gibberish.

For example:
"asdasx123ax" - gibberish
"dsjkklcq" - gibberish
"12das" - gibberish
"samarta" - not gibberish (note that it doesn't have to be a real word from the dictionary in order to be considered "not gibberish")
"karatko" - not gibberish

Basically I'm going to analyze domain names and I want the algorithm that will give me the probability that a particular domain name is a spammy/robust/gibberish domain name.

So I'm looking more at keyboard mashing or cat-like-typing gibberish.

P.S. I'm focusing on English language. And I will be happy with an algorithm that is not 100% precise and if it sometimes goes wrong, if the probability of successfully detecting gibberish (how I defined it above) is > 0.6, I will consider it a viable algorithm for my needs.

Maybe there are libraries or algorithms in Java that solve this problem?

Comment: What is your definition of *gibberish*?

Comment: Not without a clear definition of gibberish. For example words such as `Hottentottententententoonstelling` or `Bullaunancheathrairaluinn` sound like gibberish and have a length and repetition that make them look like gibberish but they aren't actually gibberish.

From your examples I would guess you're looking at keyboard mashing or cat-like-typing but that is just a guess.

Comment: With longer texts you could try counting letter frequency or use some other statistical method to determine whether a string is just a random sequence of letters or has the imprint of a human language. But with words only a few characters long that doesn't work either.

Comment: Would you consider `Strčprstskrzkrk` or `oaiaaiaoiaueu` as gibberish? :)

Comment: biziclop, yes I would consider Strčprstskrzkrk or oaiaaiaoiaueu as gibberish. I'm looking more at keyboard mashing or cat-like-typing gibberish, as mpkorstanje mentioned above.

Comment: "Hottentottententententoonstelling" or "Bullaunancheathrairaluinn" - well this I won't consider gibberish. You are right, I'm looking more at keyboard mashing or cat-like-typing.

Comment: @Vitaly Yet they are both meaningful sentences, one in Czech, the other in Romanian. You need to narrow your problem down to a certain language or at least a specific custom dictionary. Or if you're happy with an algorithm that sometimes goes wrong, you can count letter repetitions and say if there are too many or too few letters repeated, it's probably gibberish. Or count the number of vowels/consonants or something similar.

Comment: @biziclop yes, you are right. I'm focusing on English language. And I will be happy with an algorithm that is not 100% precise of course and if it sometimes goes wrong, if the probability of successfully detecting gibberish (how I defined it above) is > 0.6, I will consider it a viable algorithm for my needs.

Comment: I don't see how you could determine if it was gibberish without comparing each word to a dictionary. Without that, you could have false results.

Comment: I'd probably start with looking at the proportion and spacing of consonants and vowels. Eg Few English words have more than three consonants in a row. Or more than three vowels in a row for that matter. There are a few exceptions but you can probably make an exception table.

Comment: @Ascalonian yes, of course it can't be 100% accurate, but I guess that there are some algorithms of string analysis that use some rules of English language to determine whether the word is "valid". I mean if a human can detect it, I'm sure there are some algorithms. Question is how accurate they can be, but accuracy is not of a big importance to me, as I said if it's at least 60% accurate in detecting cat-like-typing gibberish text, it just may be enough for me.

Comment: @Jaydee that sounds closer to the problem I'm talking about, but I want to know if there are any libraries that already do that, since It's not an easy task and I don't want to invent the bicycle. Maybe someone has some code snippets, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: @Vitaly Sorry, not that I know of.

Comment: @Jaydee it's OK, I guess I'll wait a little more and if no one would suggest a working library or an algorithm, I would have to create it myself using useful tips from you, biziclop and others. But until that I hope I can avoid that and find an existing solution :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the English language, this is how I'd calculate the credibility score of each word:

- Award points for a plausible vowel/consonant ratio
- Deduct points for the presence of numbers
- Award points for the existence of common letter combinations ("ee", "oo", "ey", "th", "ch", "sh", "qu")
- Deduct points for common keyboard-mashing combinations ("asdf", "qwer", "q" followed by anything other than "u" ) and so on.

Then I'd get a long list of words and fine-tune it.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful advice. I will totally make use of it if I won't find any other solutions.

Comment: The idea of giving points is excellent ! You may also add some neg point for too many `y` and `z` and use some physocological tricks like most name's last or 2nd last is a vowel (and also 3rd) . Also chk for repetition of single letter many times

Answer (score 4):

If you have **enough** "annotated" data, you could use some kind of supervised machine learning approach, e.g. support vector machines (Java Implementation: [LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/)), which are known to perform well for text-classification tasks.

I would try to

- collect data and annotate it
- train an SVM based on n-gram-features
- (maybe optimize the SVM model)
- use the trained SVM to detect "gibberish" and "not gibberish" (binary classification)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to separate english from gibberish; Try matching the word with an english dictionary using some form of [approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) algorithm.

You could also come upp with some rules for how words should be structured, e.g too many consonants or vowels in a row would be gibberish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the link provided in your comment is invalid. Or it's auto-generated link in which case I guess it's not your fault. :)